# How to define the OpenAPI schema for a JSON object where keys are property values of its "metadata" property?

Tags: json, openapi, jsonschema

Here is the JSON response:

```json
{
    "metaData": {
        "totalProperty": "results",
        "root": "data",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "enabled"
            },
            {
                "name": "name"
            },
            {
                "name": "messages"
            }
        ]
    },
    "results": 2,
    "data": [
        {
            "enabled": true,
            "name": "file1.txt",
            "messages": 1
        },
        {
            "enabled": false,
            "name": "file2.txt",
            "messages": null
        }
    ]
}
```

where the keys `results` and `data` are the property values of `metaData`. In addition, the properties of each item in the `data` array are values of `name` in the `fields` array of `metaData`. How can I define the OpenAPI schema for this object?

I have looked into `additionalProperties`, but not sure if or how that's going to work in this case.

Comment: JSON schema and by extension open api, has no constraints that one field must relate to another